# Trying to use an OR Apache Solr search filter, but it defaults to the last value in URL

Tags: php, url, drupal, solr

So I'm trying to do an Apache Solr search in Drupal, with the following URL:

http://domain.com/en-US/resource-library?f[0]=sm_field_resource_type%3ASupport%20Documents&f[0]=sm_field_resource_type%3ADatasheets

However, this is only pulling up the Datasheets.

If, however, I do only the first part (losing everything after the &), I get only Support Documents.

How do I get an OR search in Apache Solr?

I've been reading previous examples that deal with this, and they do not seem to match up with my particular situation

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Drupal. But the query in Solr for OR query should be like

```
http://domain.com/en-US/resource-library?q=sm_field_resource_type:"Support Documents" OR sm_field_resource_type:Datasheets
```

Assuming `http://domain.com/en-US/resource-library?` is your Solr URL.
Replaced `f[0]` by **q** as per Solr standard.